# Ethereum node discovery

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

How do the nodes of Ethereum discover each other? Can there be a risk of centralisation or control over the discovery protocol or bootstrap nodes by few people in the network?

Comment: Yes, the bootnodes are the only centralized part of the network, but if somebody attacks them, it will be easy to post new IP addresses on Reddit or Twitter and the network will continue to work. Also, if your node is restarted, other peers will connect to you without bootnodes, because they remember your IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nulik but what happens in case the IP addresses change due to dynamic IP address allocation by the ISPs? This still needs to be updated in some central place ? arent we back to square one? and does this mean it is not fully decentralised

Comment: if the IP address changes then you lose the node. However your node has the IP addresses of peers stored in its internal cache and when it goes back online it will connect. So you can restart your server , get a new ip and it is going to connect again.